# Calculating Time Complexity

Tags: code-analysis, big-o

Need some Help Regarding how to calculate the time complexity of a function. e.g.

```
while(x<N)
{
   while(y<N)
     {
       stat 1;
       if(..)
          stat;
     }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean big O notation? What do you need help with? What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Also, why is this tagged with five different languages (one of which can't have anything to do with your code)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you missed a few languages.  I don't see Cobol or BeFunge

Comment: Based on the code given, I would expect an endless loop.  Perhaps you would like to provide more detail to your example.

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to Big O notation and have the patience to learn from the best, watch the first 2 video [lessons](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/) from this MIT algorithms course. This was delivered by Leiserson himself.

Answer (score 1):

the above code snippet is bounded above by O(N^2) and below by a constant...

that is when x and y are both 0, and x = y = N respectively...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x` and `y` start from `0` and are incremented by `1` in each corresponding loop, it looks like O(N^2).

If you want to compute the exact number of instructions, you should post some concrete code.